# A form that has it's display set to none keeps on appearing when the page is opened

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the form in the html file

```
<form  id="rescheduleD" action="">

<h3> Select a date:</h3> <input type="date" name="choosedate">
   <br>
   <h3>Pick a time :</h3>  <select name = "choosetime">
     <option>10 AM</option>
     <option>11 AM</option>
     <option>12 PM</option>
   </select><br>
   <br>
<input type="submit" onclick="closeReschedule();" value="Reserve Vaccination">
</form>
```

here is the button that is supposed to make the form appear

```
<button type="button" value ="Reschedule" onclick="rescheduleApp();"> Reschedule</button>
```

here is the css for the form

```
#rescheduleD{
  display: none;
}
```

here is the javascript function connected to the button

```
function rescheduleApp(){
      document.getElementById('rescheduleD').style.display = 'block';

    }
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the display property of the gets `overridden` in any places ?

Comment: @jcubic, `#rescheduleD{
  display: none;
}` will do the same(`almost`) right ?

Comment: Your code seem to work perfectly fine: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyw1as8L/). Your CSS is probably being overridden somewhere.

Comment: #rescheduleD{
  display: none !important; 
}

Comment: @SanKrish yes I have checked and it is not overridden anywhere

Comment: Or somewhere the `function rescheduleApp()` may be called during page loading

Comment: they problem in your css style, not in javascript can you post your full css so we can know what is excatly the problem, or can you add `#rescheduleD{ display: none; color: red}` and tell me if the color changed to red

Comment: Remove rescheduleApp(), function and check.

Comment: @Noha you need to provide more code or a live example, otherwise its hard to spot a problem, which is not present in your code quoted above.

Comment: Inspect the form and co to the computed tab, then at the `display` attribute you can see what is it's current value and which is the selector that applies it.